# String array size and for loop to access element

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, logic

So this is one relating to ques. on codechef(https://www.codechef.com/problems/FRK). I can't figure out why i need to increase the size of String array by 1 and run the loop for less than equal to(<=) rather than just less than(<)to access each element in array.

```
  int nooffriends=0;
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z0-9.]");
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  int noofUsers=scan.nextInt();

  if(noofUsers<1||noofUsers>5000)
      return;
  String array[]=new String[noofUsers+1];  //need to increase this size to get correct answer
  for(int i=0;i<=noofUsers;i++){     //had to put '<=' instead '<'(why)
      array[i]=scan.nextLine();

//    if(array[i].charAt(0)<89||array[i].charAt(0)>122)
//      return;
      Matcher m = p.matcher(array[i]);

      if (m.find())
        break;
      if(array[i].contains("ch")||array[i].contains("he")||array[i].contains("ef"))
      nooffriends++;
  }
  System.out.print(nooffriends);
```

}
}

Comment: why do you need an array anyway? If you just operate on the current element

Comment: that's hell of a great solution.I don't need that array.Thanks.But even though i would like to know the reason for increase in size..

Comment: It doesn't increase in size. As I wrote in the answer  nextInt() doesn't read the new line symbol. That's why in your loop the first nextLine() reads the new line from the previous call to nextInt(). Just add an extra nextLine() before the loop and you are good to go

Comment: Or just always use nextline() and then parse to int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you scan for nextInt() you don't terminate the line. So next call to nextLine() actually reads the same line of the input. If you check the contents of your array you will see that the [0] element is empty. Also if you print i in the loop you will see that it lets you input on the 1st element and 0 element is skipped.

In order to fix it add an scan.nextLine() after your nextInt() and it will work as expected:

```
    System.out.print("Number of users:");
    int noofUsers = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine(); //Add that!

    if (noofUsers < 1 || noofUsers > 5000)
        return;
    String array[] = new String[noofUsers]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < noofUsers; i++) { 
        System.out.print("Scan:["+i+"]");
        array[i] = scan.nextLine();

        Matcher m = p.matcher(array[i]);

        if (m.find())
            break;
        if (array[i].contains("ch") || array[i].contains("he") || array[i].contains("ef"))
            nooffriends++;
    }
```

Another even simpler solution would be:

```
  for (int i = 0; i <= noofUsers; i++) { 
        String currentMember=scan.nextLine();
        Matcher m = p.matcher(currentMember);
        if (m.find())
            break;
        if (currentMember.contains("ch") || currentMember.contains("he") || currentMember.contains("ef"))
            nooffriends++;
    }
```

You don't need to store all answers in an array. You can just operate with the current one and then forget it ;)

Comment: I am glad I helped. You can always upvote or accept the answer in return ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's because the line

```
  int noofUsers=scan.nextInt();
```

I'm not sure your input file format. But if it look like this:

```
123\n
xxxxx\n
xxxx\n
```

the function 'nextInt' only get 123. And the other text is:

```
\n
xxxxxx\n
xxxxxx\n
```

If you want to go to next line ,you  need read a \n.
So, you need run an additional nextLine() to get the nextLine.